# Error in using 'import' in webpack.config.babel.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import path from 'path'
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

This error occurs when I use `webpack-dev-server --hot`.

It seems like this occurs because it can't read `import` or webpack doesn't support `import`. I tried to use `babel-register` but it doesn't work. Is there any way to solve this problem? Refer to the code below.

**webpack.config.babel.js**

```
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import HtmlPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'

const vueLoaders = {
  html: 'pug-loader',
  css: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    use: 'css-loader',
    fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
  }),
  scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
  sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
}

export default {
  entry: './client/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'),
    new HtmlPlugin({
      title: 'sex',
      template: 'client/assets/index.pug'
    })
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: 'css-loader', fallback: 'style-loader'
        })
      }, {
        test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'], fallback: 'style-loader'
        })
      }, {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: 'pug-loader'
      }, {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }, {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: { loaders: vueLoaders }
      }, {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ttf|woff2?|eot)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: { name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]' }
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
  },

  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: '"production"' }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: { warnings: false }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ minimize: true })
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node does not support ES6 `import` syntax at the moment. Use CommonJS `require` syntax in the meanwhile.

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
```

Answer (score 6):

`babel-register` only transforms the modules you require with babel where you call `require("babel-register");`, not the module itself.

You can use an intermediate step to make this work with the Webpack configuration.

#### webpack.config.js

```
require('babel-register');
module.exports = require('./webpack.config.babel.js');
```

#### webpack.config.babel.js

```
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import HtmlPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'

const vueLoaders = {
  html: 'pug-loader',
  css: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created a webpack.config.js and when tying to execute `webpack` you are getting above error. Cause your webpack config file need to be `babelified` before you can use it,

1) Rename your `webpack.config.js` to `webpack.config.babel.js`.

2) Now create a new file `webpack.config.js` with just the following **2 lines**

```
require('babel-register');
module.exports = require('./webpack.config.babel.js');
```

3) create a `.babelrc` file in parallel to your `webpack.config.js` file with following content. We need to tell babel explicitly what preset to use.

```
{
  "presets": ["latest",'react', 'es2015','stage-2']
}
```

4) add following node modules to your dependency ( Required for presets used in `.babelrc`)

```
npm install babel-preset-env babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-2 babel-preset-latest babel-preset-react --save-dev
```

5) You are done . Now if you execute `webpack --progress --colors --watch` it should work.